# NSString to char[]?

Tags: objective-c

```
struct DATA
{
    unsigned char USERNAME[32];
};
```

i want copy a `NSString` to struct `DATA.USERNAME` , how to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `-[NSString UTF8String]` method to get a C string of your NSString. Then, you can use `strncpy(DATA.USERNAME, [mystring UTF8String], 32);` to copy that string into the structure.

Comment: also, if you need USERNAME to be null terminated, add `DATA.USERNAME[31] = '\0';`

Comment: @cobbal ehrm, what if the string is not exactly 30 characters in length? You can get memory crap appended to it.

Comment: @WTP If it's a null terminated string you're after, then it doesn't matter what comes after the \0. "Foo\0" is equivalent to "Foo\0randomstuff\0".

Comment: @cobbal I know that, but you are expecting the string to be exactly 30 bytes (hence `DATA.USERNAME[31] = '\0';`). The crap will be between the end of the string and the `\0`.

Comment: @WTP If the string is less that 32 bytes long, then `strncopy` will also place a \0 at the correct end of the string, and the one at 31 will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to know what encoding is expected. NSString can generate bytes in a wide range of encodings. Then you pass a pointer to the `USERNAME` array to `getCString:maxLength:encoding:`. So, for example, if you want to copy the contents of the NSString `myCocoaString` as UTF-8 into USERNAME field of a DATA struct called `myData`, you'd do:

```
BOOL success = [myCocoaString getCString:myData.USERNAME maxLength:32 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"Was %@ to store string contents in USERNAME!", success ? @"able" : @"not able");
```

Comment: The *CString* methods of NSString are largely deprecated.  Use the UTF8String methods instead.